# Show that $S_N(x + y) > S_N(x) + S_N(y) - 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$S_N(x)$ is the function $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}$ where   $x,y > 0$

My (attempted) Solution: $$S_N(x+y) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{{n\choose 0}x^n +{n\choose 1}x^{n-1}y +...+{n\choose n-1}xy^{n-1}+{n\choose n}y^n }{n!}$$

$$S_N(x) + S_N(y) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{y^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n+y^n}{n!}$$

And $x^n +...+ y^n > x^n + y^n$

And done?

Comment: Not completely. If you do not take care of one subtlety, your argument seems to prove the (wrong) inequality $S_N(x+y)>S_(x)+S_N(y)$. Additionally, the problem statement itself needs to be more specific about $N$ because the inequality as stated is false for $N=1$ and for $N=0$.

Comment: @Mehak Wahla You have done a good job. Your argument is fine for $N>1$ and it proves the stronger inequality $S_N(x+y)>S_N(x)+S_N(y)$. Just note that for $N=0$ and $N=1$ strict inequality does not hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, if $S_N(x+y)\gt S_N(x)+S_N(y)$ held for all positive $x$ and $y$, then, letting $y\to0$, we would have $S_N(x)\ge S_N(x)+S_N(0)=S_N(x)+1$. There's a hitch in the assertion $x^n+\cdots+y^n\gt x^n+y^n$ when $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive proof: Remark that $S'_N(x)=S_{N-1}(x)$, suppose true for $S_{N-1}$, let $y>0$ and for $x\geq 0$ define $f_N(x)=S_N(x+y)-S_N(x)-S_N(y)+1$, $f'_N(x)=S_{N-1}(x+y)-S_{N-1}(x)> S_{N-1}(y)-1>0$ since $S_{N-1}(y)>1$, so $f_N$ strictly increases, $f_N(0)=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I had a hard time following this. Could you elucidate on the meaning of $S'_N(x)$ and $S_{N-1}$?

Comment: $S'_N$ is the derivative of $S_N$.